# "Bake" with textures and visualisation

Tags: word-meaning, terminology, word-in-context

I often hear the word "**bake**" used when speaking about textures and visualisation in films, video games and 3D modeling. I don't want to sound silly but I can't quite understand this particular word in this context, not it's origins, nor it's definition.

Does it mean **compile** or **render**? Why the word **bake** and not sone other word?

Comment: This description of texture baking might help folks answer your question: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Texture_Baking I have a vague sense that it refers to "setting" a texture, similar to baking a glazed pot in a kiln to make the glaze stick to the clay an become, um, immutable. I don't know the actual origin of the term though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the English language sources I've tried, the simplest definitions of the specific "term to bake in/into" are these:

1.to incorporate (a feature) as part of a system or piece of software or hardware.

2.to include as an inseparable or permanent part

Here's [the link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bake--in) (9 a,b) in case you somehow missed it searching, and here's, since you are a Russian translator and may use Russian language resources as well,  the ["Мультиран's"](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=bake%20in)  similar definition.

**In addition:**

As for the "baking" as a process, I couldn't find anything more simple than that it refers to the action of transferring mesh based information into textures [(the source)](https://support.allegorithmic.com/documentation/display/SPDOC/Baking) , but to an average person, it seems to be rocket science (I think to most users of ELL  and surely to me, it is), but I think that the explanation of how it works and what mesh-based information is can be found on some other site.

Comment: Another common phrase in the sense of making something a permanent part: [...ALM processes **have quality baked in from the outset**...](https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-configuration-tweaks-help-bake-quality/) "Baking" a texture is a little bit different (you don't "bake in" the texture, you just bake it).

Comment: @ColleenV - Thanks for the comment--It helped me to add a few lines to my answer.

Comment: Well, I guess **bake** then means "*to prepare a texture from different ingrediences*"?

Comment: @SovereignSun - Like baking a pie? Maybe:)